# Unique user count with distinct function

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

I have a question about the distinct count.

Given a table of timestamp, user_id, country, site_id.
I want to find out the number of unique user per site.

But with my code, it is not giving me a unique user number, and I am not sure why.
I know I have 1916 unique users, but the output is giving me more than that.

Thank you in advance.

```
SELECT site_id, COUNT(distinct user_id)
FROM SWE
GROUP BY site_id
```

Comment: If you want a count of unique users: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM swe;` If you want unique users per site, then your query is correct. Perhaps your data is corrupt (string data type instead of integer, for instance)

Comment: If you have a different question, ask a different question!

Comment: You tell me, but I would have thought `COUNT(DISTINCT country_id)` would be what you're after.

Comment: I think I got it. If i want to find the number of unique users who have visited at least two different countries  per site
```
SELECT site_id, COUNT (DISTINCT user_id) 
FROM SWE 
GROUP BY site_id
HAVING COUNT(country_id) >=2
ORDER BY site_id ASC;

Comment: I don't really know what `visited at least two different countries per site` means - but it sounds like you're on the right track.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Last question, so If i want to find hte ratio between the two numbers from two different table. How would I go about it?

Comment: You would divide one by the other - a question probably best suited to a math forum.

Comment: Actually I meant on the query, how would would you link the two table...but thanks anyway

Comment: The sql term for 'linking' is JOIN. Half the internet is preoccupied with discussing this topic (the half that's not precoccupied with pictures of cats).